# Username for Update History With Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have an automated process to check the status of certain database items. I use the audited gem and would like to keep track of this task changing records by having a default username logged in the update history. I am not finding how to fake a login through any of these automated processes. Is it possible to do simply?

Comment: Do you have any codes so far?

Comment: Yes, but in general I need to know how to make this rake task return a username for the "current_user" method when active record initiates a save (for audited).

Comment: Maybe, it would be better if you can post it. So that we may also better understand your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the currently logged in user with `ENV['USER']`
Using this you could look up the user in your DB through ActiveRecord (I assume you are using Rails):

```
username = ENV['USER']
user = User.find_by!(username: username)
```

Now this might work. Or not. Depending on what you have stored in the DB, if you can make a lookup by username and if the usernames of the logged in users are also in your DB.

The difficult part is the `current_user`. This sounds much like a method that is in a controller?
How do you log the user currently?